# AutoCompleteTextView get value from ArrayList based on Position

Tags: android, json, arraylist, autocompletetextview

I am using `AutoCompleteTextView` in my program, where I am showing suggestions from *JSON* and my *JSON* looks like:

```
{"areas":[{"area_id":"1","area_name":"Area 1"},{"area_id":"2","area_name":"Area 2"}],"success":1}
```

Here is the *AutoCompleteTextView* code along with `OnItemClick`:

```
textArea.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapterAreas);

textArea.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    // along with name, I also want to fetch Id of that particular area

                    autoAreaName = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    Log.d("AreaName:", autoAreaName); // getting accurate area name

                    if(areaArrayList.contains(autoAreaName)) {

                        // how to get area id using area name

                    }

                }
            });
```

Code to *fetch* available `Areas`, from *webservice*:

```
     if (success == 1) {
     JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("areas");

     for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

     JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

     Area area = new Area();
     area.setId(jsonObject.getInt("area_id"));
     area.setName(jsonObject.getString("area_name"));

     // adding area to areas array
     stringArrayListAreas.add(jsonObject.getString("area_name"));

     areaArrayList.add(area);

     } // for loop ends


     } // if ends
```

**What is the best way to get both the values (Area Id and Name) from JSON  ?**

*UPDATED*

```
public String toString(){
    return id+":"+name;
}
```

*Activity*

```
    textArea.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Area area = new Area();
            Log.d("areaData:", area.toString());

        }
    });
```

*Lag says*

```
D/areaData:: 0:null
```

Comment: Yes. I know that I am doing some mistake, and this question really deserves Negative marking... but still I am happy because I tried what I got and now I am looking for suggestions/ guidelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best way to get both the values (Area Id and Name) from
>   JSON ?

the best way is to bind the adapter you are feeding to the AutoCompleteTextView with a model class that contains both info. E.g.

```
 public class Model {
   public String name;
   public String area_id;

   public void toString() {
      return name;
   } 
 }
```

you will have to change your code to use this class. In Your `onItemClick` you will cast to `Model` instead of `String`, and access its members to extract the information you need

Comment: Please check UPDATED section above, I posted what I have tried to get information the way you taught

Comment: if you fed up the adapter with Area objects, you will have to use `Area area = (Area) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);`

Comment: Really sorry, but still getting: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast

Comment: you have to change your adapter to use `Area`. Map your json to a collection of `Area` and feed up your adapter  with this collection, instead of a collection of String

Comment: thank you for your humble and sweet help... thanks finally I have created Custom Adapter class

Comment: you don't need a custom subclass of an Adapter. You need to show only name, just override `toString` and use `ArrayAdapter<Area>` instead of `ArrayAdapter<String>`

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried same, but now not getting suggestions, please check code here: http://pastebin.com/7MWwqXyT

Comment: Could add Area to the pastbin as well ?

Comment: I got it... actually if I write 1 or 2 or 3 then showing 1:First Area Name and 2:Second Area Name whereas I just want to show Area Name in Suggestions, Area ID I want to get for my personal purpose, here is code with Area: http://pastebin.com/WK8Z1j2i

Comment: change toString to return only name. OnItemClick then use area.getId()

Comment: Finally DONE and found that was very easy and tons of thanks to showing me the easiest way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

first use the models class in adapter to get and set details, and then get the data on itemclicklister like:

```
((DataModel)listview.getAdapter().getItem(position)).getarea_id();
```